# Flutter : border and borderRadius cannot use together

Tags: flutter

I trying to create the layout like below image. But when I add `borderRadius` to curve `Container`, error appear

[image]

```
Container(
  height: 40,
  width: 40,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.black,
    border: Border(
      bottom: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Color(0xFF1A87EF)),
      left: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Color(0xFF1A87EF)),
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100)
    )
  ),
  child: Icon(Icons.settings, color: Color(0xFF1A87EF), size: 20,),
),
```

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
A borderRadius can only be given for a uniform Border.
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `BorderRaduis`

```
Container(
        height: 40,
        width: 40,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xFF1A87EF), width: 1.0),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50),
          ),
        ),
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.settings,
          color: Color(0xFF1A87EF),
          size: 20,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Hi, as you can see the attached image , border are only `bottom` and `left` , your suggested solution is all bordered.

Comment: I tried but cant put border only in `bottom` & `left` and others be `none`! i think it's impossible, you can paint your own `container` or you can give `boxShadow` just one side to make some kind of border.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible just with border as you are required to pass all BorderSide(top,bottom,left,right) if you want to use borderRadius Property and all BorderSide should be same.

There is one other way to do that. You can use Stack and clip it. See the code below, it does exactly what you want but with stack

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestView extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            children: [
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: const Color(0xFF1A87EF),
                      width: 3,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                  ),
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  child: const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.settings,
                      color: Color(0xFF1A87EF),
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 50,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```